# In Python, how do you return a list of nested lists, with one element changing location?

Tags: python, list, nested

For example, say I have a list of lists such as this:

```
ls = [['','a','b'],
      ['d','',''],
      ['','','c']]
```

Can I add another item, say 'x' into the empty slots one at a time and create a list of all outcomes?

To clarify, since there are 5 empty spaces, I would want 5 new copies of ls, each with only one added 'x', just in a different spot each time.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: The question is really unclear, can you give an example of desired output

Answer (score 4):

You can use a generator function to find each position where there is an empty string then [deepcopy](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy) as you iterate over the positions yielding a new copy with the next pos set to x:

```
def yield_pos(ls):
    for ind, sub in enumerate(ls):
        for ind2, ele in enumerate(sub):
            if not ele:
                 yield ind, ind2

from copy import deepcopy
def step(ls):
    ls_cp = deepcopy(ls)
    for i,j in yield_pos(ls):
        ls_cp[i][j] = "x"
        yield ls_cp
        ls_cp = deepcopy(ls_cp)

for cop in step(ls):
    print(cop)
```

Output:

```
[['x', 'a', 'b'], ['d', '', ''], ['', '', 'c']]
[['x', 'a', 'b'], ['d', 'x', ''], ['', '', 'c']]
[['x', 'a', 'b'], ['d', 'x', 'x'], ['', '', 'c']]
[['x', 'a', 'b'], ['d', 'x', 'x'], ['x', '', 'c']]
[['x', 'a', 'b'], ['d', 'x', 'x'], ['x', 'x', 'c']]
```

If you want just one each time not keeping the previous updated x's then we just need the first logic:

```
from copy import deepcopy

def yield_copy_x(ls):
    for ind, sub in enumerate(ls):
        for ind2, ele in enumerate(sub):
            if not ele:
                new = deepcopy(ls)
                new[ind][ind2] = "x"
                yield new



for cop in yield_copy_x(ls):
    print(cop)
```

Which gives you:

```
[['x', 'a', 'b'], ['d', '', ''], ['', '', 'c']]
[['', 'a', 'b'], ['d', 'x', ''], ['', '', 'c']]
[['', 'a', 'b'], ['d', '', 'x'], ['', '', 'c']]
[['', 'a', 'b'], ['d', '', ''], ['x', '', 'c']]
[['', 'a', 'b'], ['d', '', ''], ['', 'x', 'c']]
```

If you want a list of lists you can just call list:

```
 print(list(yield_copy_x(ls)))
```

Which will give you:

```
[[['x', 'a', 'b'], ['d', '', ''], ['', '', 'c']], [['', 'a', 'b'], ['d', 'x', ''], ['', '', 'c']], [['', 'a', 'b'], ['d', '', 'x'], ['', '', 'c']], [['', 'a', 'b'], ['d', '', ''], ['x', '', 'c']], [['', 'a', 'b'], ['d', '', ''], ['', 'x', 'c']]]
```

But unless you really need a list at once, you can just iterate over the generator function as in the firs example.

Comment: Question says:
"I would want 5 new copies of ls, each with `only one` added 'x', just in a different spot each time."

Comment: @HEADLESS_0NE, then just the first part is needed.

Comment: No worries, unless you really need a list you can just iterate getting a copy at a time. using a  generator function lets you yield one value at a time without need to store all data in memory at once which for large data is very useful

Comment: @PadraicCunningham...the link to `deepcopy` is for Python2...shouldn't be [Python3](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy)'s version instead?

Comment: @IronFist, not sure what the OP is using, I changed for python3 but I don't think there is much difference between either.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham .. Never mind, just thought you intended to refer to verson3. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import copy

ls = [['','a','b'],
      ['d','',''],
      ['','','c']]

def get_index():
    # Function to get the index which match the criteria.
    for index0, list0 in enumerate(ls):
        for index1, item in enumerate(list0):
            if item == '':
                # The criteria matches, yield the indexes.
                yield index0, index1

def edit_ls():
    final_list = []
    for index0, index1 in get_index():
        # Copy the original list.
        new_ls = copy.deepcopy(ls)
        # at the index set value.
        new_ls[index0][index1] = 'x'
        # Append the list to final result.
        final_list.append(new_ls)
    return final_list
```

Comment: If you like the answer, can you upvote it or mark it correct? Thanks